# I got this error"operator + cannot be applied to java.lang.string void"

Tags: inheritance, java

I tried to call a method in `println`from a super class using the object that I have created for the super class. I got this error

> "operator + cannot be applied to java.lang.string void"

```
System.out.println("Contents of objsuper: " + objsuper.showij());
```

Comment: Your `showij()` method has the return type `void`. That means that it does **not** return any result. So it is impossible to add a _result_ to the string in order to print it - there is no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line

```
System.out.println("Contents of objsuper: " + objsuper.showij());
```

with

```
System.out.println("Contents of objsuper: ");
objsuper.showij();
```

The reason for this is, the return type of `objsuper.showij()` is `void` and therefore, `operator +` cannot be applied to it. A `void` method is like doing something but not returning a value and since there is no value returned by it, you can not append it to anything using `+` operator; you need to call it separately the way I have done above.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the method `objsuper.showij()` you will that it returns nothing `void`

This can not be appended to something

Answer (score 0):

In Syso '+' is a way for string literal concatenation. You can use string or objects with a toString() method. As void fuction doesn't return anything, you cant use it in System.out.println